# What is return type for grails service function?

Tags: grails, projection, criteriaquery

I having a grails service function like this

```
public List<Object> getfunction(def test, def test1) {
  def criteria = Test.createCriteria();
  List<Object> list= criteria.list {
      projections{
          groupProperty('state')
          rowCount()
      }
  }
}
```

But I bit confused about the return type of this 
function, with current implementation it is working, but I know it is wrong return type.

Please suggest, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think the return type is wrong?

Comment: No it is just plain right ?

Comment: Criteria with projections return List<Object>, so yes it's right.

Comment: ohhh... thank you, I had bit doubt about it. Thank you for time. Also let me check.

Comment: `println getfunction(...)` is the best doubt killer >)

Answer (score 2):

The code you written is working since grails uses groovy and in groovy the last statement of method is used for return. So whatever you write at the end of any method will be returned unless function type is **void**.

For example:

```
String getFullName() {
    String firstName = "S"
    String lastName = "A"

    firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

This will return the concatenated string automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.  All of the following do the exact same thing:

```
public List<Object> getfunction(def test, def test1) {
    def criteria = Test.createCriteria();
    List<Object> list= criteria.list {
        projections{
            groupProperty('state')
            rowCount()
        }
    }
}

public List<Object> getfunction(def test, def test1) {
    def criteria = Test.createCriteria();
    List<Object> list= criteria.list {
        projections{
            groupProperty('state')
            rowCount()
        }
    }
    return list
}

public List<Object> getfunction(def test, def test1) {
    def criteria = Test.createCriteria();
    List<Object> list= criteria.list {
        projections{
            groupProperty('state')
            rowCount()
        }
    }
    list
}

public List<Object> getfunction(def test, def test1) {
    def criteria = Test.createCriteria();
    return criteria.list {
        projections{
            groupProperty('state')
            rowCount()
        }
    }
}

public List<Object> getfunction(def test, def test1) {
    def criteria = Test.createCriteria();
    criteria.list {
        projections{
            groupProperty('state')
            rowCount()
        }
    }
}
```

The return statement is optional.  When there is no return statement then whatever the last expression evaluates to, that is returned.

I hope that helps.